# Twilio Queue Sid

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using the following code that I got from the twilio website. I need to get the QueueSid of my queue named "Sales". How do I go  about doing this? If there is documentation for this subject please point me there as well. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$accountSid = "ACYYYYYYYYYY"; 
$authToken = "XXXXXXXXX"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($accountSid,$authToken);

// Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page
$member = $client->account->queues->get('QU5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659')->members->get("Front");
$member->update(array(
    "Url" => "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11489766/learn/voice.xml",
    "Method" => "POST"
));
echo $member->wait_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can search for all of your queues using the [Queues list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#list). Then you will want to filter by the Friendly name to get your queue. Try something like this:

```
<?php
  // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
  require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

  // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
  $accountSid = "ACYYYYYYYYYY"; 
  $authToken = "XXXXXXXXX"; 

  $client = new Services_Twilio($accountSid, $authToken);

  foreach($client->account->queues as $queue){
      if ($queue->friendly_name == "Sales"){
          $foundQueue = $queue;
          break;
      }
  }
  echo $foundQueue;
```